# How to estimate a Hadoop Cluster?

Tags: hadoop

Can anybody help me in getting some useful ideas for estimating the size of a hadoop cluster and cluster hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it all depends on the amount of data you are handling and what exactly you are catering to. But, you can refer to this pdf [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://bigdata.googlecode.com/files/Hadoop%2520The%2520Definitive%2520Guide%25202nd%2520Edition.pdf&ei=wFpBUbWpO8KHrAfy7YHYBg&usg=AFQjCNEUBmk-aImn8iz07qj8koVXwQ6xag&sig2=FkHs-mkZ1RN2osIYWiBkTg&bvm=bv.43287494,d.bmk&cad=rja), to get more insight on how you can estimate.